# Jmeter results are greyed out

Tags: testing, jmeter

[image]

Can anyone tell me which setting can allow me to see my JMeter results?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to right click on 'View Results Tree' and select Toggle!

Answer (score 2):

Similarly you can explicitly 'Enable' the component. Enable and its counter-part Disable are concrete commands, Toggle swaps between the two states.

These options are available from the right-click menu, and from the Edit menu, when the component is selected.